# get array of equidistant timestamps out of time range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two time stamps

```
const start_time = '2020-03-11 17:18:50';
const end_time = '2020-03-11 17:19:45'
```

How to get an array of timestamps with lets say step=50 points, which are the equidistant intervals between start_time and end_time?

It should look something like:

```
[
 '2020-03-11 17:18:50',
 '2020-03-11 17:18:57',
 '2020-03-11 17:19:03',
 '2020-03-11 17:19:10',
 ...,
 '2020-03-11 17:19:45'
]
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?  Can you show us where you're stuck?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Please, why people downgrade a question? I generally do a lot of research on a topic before posting to the stackoverflow. And I was running of time as well.

Comment: I did not down-vote, and I have no idea who did.  But there is a strong consensus here that a good question *demonstrates* the effort the questioner put into it.  If you showed us some code you'd written, people would be much more likely to offer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this snippet answers your question. You can find a step size in milliseconds and create Date objects from the timestamps.

```js
const start_time = '2020-03-11 17:18:50';
const end_time = '2020-03-11 17:19:45';
const steps = 50;

const startTimestamp = new Date(start_time).getTime();
const endTimestamp = new Date(end_time).getTime();
const stepSize = (endTimestamp - startTimestamp) / steps;

for (let i = 1; i < steps; ++i) {
    const stepDate = new Date(startTimestamp + i * stepSize);
    console.log(stepDate);
}
```